# cakephp: how to display associated records of associated records

Tags: cakephp, find, recursive-query

My objective is to display records for a related child model (once removed) in the view. I understand that setting the recursive value to '1' returns the current model, its owner(s), plus their associated models.

What I don't know how to do is display this in the view.

My approach has been to create a varialable in the controller holding the value of the associated model ID, but that hasn't work.

*I should also mention that I'm using a sluggable behavior for tournaments, so it's not $id that is used but $slug.

Here are the model view controller details:

Model

tournament - has many tournamentDetails

tournamentDetails - has many updates

updates - belongs to tournamentDetails

tournaments controller
action = view

```
class TournamentsController extends AppController 

function view($slug = null) {
  if (!$slug) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Tournament.', true));
      $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
  }
$this->Tournament->recursive = 1;
$tournament = $this->Tournament->findBySlug($slug);
$updates = $this->Tournament->TournamentDetail->Update->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('update.tournament_detail_id' => $this->data['tournament_details'] ['id'] )) );
$this->set(compact('tournament','updates' ));
```

Tournament view. This is display the 'tournament details' and (ideally) related tournament detail 'updates'

```
<h2><?php echo $tournament['Tournament']['name']; ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($tournament['TournamentDetail'] as $tournamentDetail): ?>
 <h1><?php echo $tournamentDetail ['title']; ?></h1>
 <p><?php echo $tournamentDetail ['body']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($updates['Update'] as $update): ?>
 <h4>Update: <?php echo $update  ['date']; ?></h4>
 <p> <?php echo $update ['Update'] ['title']; ?></p>
 <p><?php echo $update ['Update'] ['body']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

when I debug $updates, this is all I see:

```
Array
(
)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Is it not correct to construct the find conditions by using:

```
 ('conditions'=>array('update.tournament_detail_id' => $this->data['tournament_details'] ['id'] )
```

Thanks for the help.
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) Behavior to specify in detail what fields you want to obtain from associated models, associated models to associated models and so on. Then you will find all data inside the array `$tournament`, like in the examples in the link.

**EDIT** (in response the OP comment). I think that the problem may be using the magic `findBy` method. You would need to substitute that with the standard `find`, like in this example

```
$tournament = $this->Tournament->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'slug' => $slug
    ),
    'contain' => array(//Put here the settings for Containable
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I've been working with Containable throughout the day to see if it would work. I believe it can but the problem I run into is that I'm also using a Sluggable behaviour, the find looks like this: $this->Tournament->findBySlug($slug); When I tried to attach a 'contain' array to it I got errors. So then I created a new variable, added contain and I get a 'Notice (8): Undefined index: error. So, any ideas? Do you need more info? When I pr() the new variable I do get the correct results.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, using coding in your edit did work. However, I still get the error in the view (Notice (8): Undefined index:) and I don't understand why. The view code looks like this for 'updates', <?php foreach ($tournament ['Update'] as $update): ?>
   <h3>Update: <?php echo $update ['date']; ?></h3>
     <h4><?php echo $update ['title']; ?></h4>
     <p><?php echo $update  ['body']; ?></p>
   <hr/>
<?php endforeach; ?> Is it obvious from this loop where the undefined index would come from?

Comment: I cannot see it. But you should, since where you have an undefined index you should have missing data. Do all data display as expected? Is it possible that the Notice comes from elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Andrea, none of the data for the 'updates' loop displays. I first get the 'undefined index' error and then the error for incorrect 'foreach' loop. When I debug the 'tournament' variable in the view I do see the associated model records, but the foreach loop throws this undefined index error. I've tried so many different way to resolve this, very frustrating. Thanks again, Paul